Direct proof that $\sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=0}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x(n-y)} = \sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x^2}$
I'm looking for a direct proof that for all $n\in \mathbb N$, $$\sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=0}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x(n-y)} = \sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x^2}.$$
It is easy to prove this relation by induction on $n$, but I'm struggling to find a direct proof. The relation is so simple that it feels like there should be a short non-inductive proof, potentially using other well-known identities.
Note that subtracting $\left(\sum_{x=1}^n \frac 1 x\right)^2$ from both side, the relation is equivalent to
$$\sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^{n-x} \frac{1}{xy}=\sum_{1\leq x\ne y \leq n} \frac{1}{xy}.$$
So a direct proof of this latter equality would also be sufficient.

One can prove
$$
\sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^{n-x} \frac{1}{xy}=\sum_{1\leq x\ne y \leq n} \frac{1}{xy}
$$
by collecting on the left-hand side all terms with $x+y = s$, $2 \le s \le n$:
$$
\sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^{n-x} \frac{1}{xy} 
= \sum_{s=2}^n \sum_{x=1}^{s-1} \frac{1}{x(s-x)}
= \sum_{s=2}^n \sum_{x=1}^{s-1} \frac 1s \left( \frac 1x + \frac{1}{s-x}\right) \\
= \sum_{s=2}^n \frac 1s \left( \sum_{x=1}^{s-1} \frac 1x + \sum_{x=1}^{s-1} \frac{1}{s-x}\right) \, .
$$
The two sums in the parentheses are equal, so this is
$$
 \cdots = 2 \sum_{s=2}^n \frac 1s \sum_{x=1}^{s-1} \frac 1x
= 2 \sum_{1 \le x < s \le n} \frac{1}{xs}
= \sum_{\substack{ x, y = 1 \\x \ne y }}^n\frac{1}{xy} \, .
$$
As you said, this implies the original identity:
$$
\begin{align}
 \sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=0}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x(n-y)}
&= \left( \sum_{x=1}^n \frac 1x \right)^2 - \sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{y=1}^{n-x} \frac{1}{xy} \\
&= \left( \sum_{x=1}^n \frac 1x \right)^2 - \sum_{\substack{ x, y = 1 \\x \ne y }}^n\frac{1}{xy} \\
&=  \sum_{x=1}^n \frac 1{x^2} \, .
\end{align}
$$
